How can I programmatically set a custom homepage without showing the pages alias?
I have a system where a user can add a custom domain, for example *domain.com, in a text field. For example in node 10. This custom domain should, when entered in the browser, end up in showing the node where the custom domain is filled in.
I can get this partly working using a EventSubscriber but the problem is that when the url is filled in the url changes. So I go to domain.com and the url instantly changes to domain.com/node/10. Is there a way to do this differently so the url stays the same?
I am looking for a Drupal solution, not a htaccess solution. And one using a custom module or custom code I don't want to use the Domain module.

This is config. You can ignore the config from sync and set and save config programmatically yourself with whatever the user enters. Or what is the exact problem? I don't get the URL part. Where does it instantly change? In the browser? In the config form?

We ignore the frontpage setting for this very reason. Uses can set it at any time they want.

They can't set it per-domain though, which is what the OP is asking...

I suppose the OP is redirecting in the EventSubscriber mentioned. Changing the URL based on the domain internally without showing it in the browser would be path processing and yes, frontpage settings are also implemented via path processing, so all of this is kind of connected.

Generate a path processor:
drush gen path-processor

Set a priority higher than 200 to override the core PathProcessorFront.
Change the path for the front page depending on the domain:
  public function processInbound($path, Request $request) {
    if ($path === '/') {
      // determine the path and set it
      $path = '/node/??';
    }
    return $path; 
  }

While this answers how can i programmatically set a custom homepage, for the domain-specific part you need to Disable caching for a front page path processor, you've asked some time ago.

Thanks for this simple answer. I tried this on a clean installed Drupal website and this is working great. When I want to show node 90 it works perfectly and only the domain is shown so: domain.com. When I try this on an existing website (with the same module) it shows node 90 and the url is changed tot domain.com/node/90?
I don't understand what the difference is, what can be the problem? Is there a way to debug this?

Got it, found out this is a setting from the redirect module.

I had to add this to my processInbound:
$config = $this->configFactory->getEditable('system.site');
$config->set('page.front', $path)->save();
To make sure the redirect module didn't force to show the alias of this custom homepage.

This is not a good idea, you should only save config on POST request. BTW did you add the extra domain cache metadata to the routing process? See the link at the end of my answer. The Redirect module could also rely on the correct caching of route collections. But I'm unsure what you need to do to make the Redirect module domain aware. This is a more complex task you can not solve in one topic here.

Hi, caching was already set using the previous post. Thanks for the tip that the config should only be set via a POST request. I'll look for a other way to get redirect to not enforce the alias one the custom frontpage.

Another idea, try $request->attributes->set('_disable_route_normalizer', true);

I ended up disabling the Enforce clean and canonical URLs from the redirect module. And wrote a custom code to enforce node/* to alias. Problem solved.

Yes, I was also trying to disable this in my last comment, but specific to the front page path. I had the impression you don't want to remove the route normalizer for the entire site. But when you are able to program parts of it yourself, perfect :-)
